# initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast when compiling

Tags: c, linux

I'am receiving werid warnings from the gcc compiler when compiling the following code:

```
  int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int fdm;
    pid_t pid;
    fdm = posix_openpt( O_RDWR );
    pid = fork();
    if(pid==0)
    {
        if(grantpt(fdm) ==-1)
        {
            perror("grantpt");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if(unlockpt(fdm) ==-1)
        {
            perror("unlockpt");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        char* name = ptsname(fdm);
        int fds = open(name,O_RDWR);
        if(fds ==-1)
        {
            perror("open");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        close(0);
        close(1);
        close(2);
        dup(fds);
        dup(fds);
        dup(fds);
        execlp("cat","cat",NULL);
        perror("cat");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf( "main: copied %d bytes\n", dblCOPY( STDIN_FILENO, fdm, fdm, STDOUT_FILENO ) );
 return 0;
}
```

and here is the warning :

```
warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   char* name = ptsname(fdm);
```

the werid thing is that ptsname function returns char pointer and not integer as compiler claims, So what may be the problem?

Comment: Probably there is no declaration of `ptsname`.  You haven't shown the `#include`'s.

Comment: In the absence of information (no prototype (missing include file?)) the compiler assumes `ptsname()` returns an `int` ... so you have `char* name = <intvalue>;` and the warning

Comment: C  defaults to int for undeclared functions.. Don't forget the feature test macro

Comment: VTC as incomplete, nice and simple. You never showed how your `main()` function/file is supposed to know the signature of `ptsname()`, so it doesn't, and unless you turn on a barely modern C standard/warnings then the compiler will try to guess for you, and then warn about its guess.

Comment: I don't see `#include <stdlib.h>` anywhere...

Comment: Whatever you do, **DO NOT ADD A CAST TO SILENCE THE WARNING**, ie.. don't do `char* name = (char*)ptsname(fdm); /* terribly bad cast!! */`

Comment: The warning is not weird. It means you do something wrong and you need to find your error.

Comment: ptsname() is function which is declared in stdlib library, And i already included that library in the top of the file

Comment: you must have much more warnings. **Read them ALL**

Comment: You need to include stdlib.h and also ensure that you compile as GNU (`-std=gnu11`) and not standard C. If you tell gcc to be standard strict `-std=cxx -pedantic-errors` it will remove misc GNU barf from standard headers where a C compiler isn't allowed to barf. How do you compile this?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to define some feature test macros before including the header files,

see man page `man feature_test_macros`

There are two ways to remove this warning,

1. define required feature test macros by adding the code above

   #define _XOPEN_SOURCE
   #define _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED

   #include <stdio.h>

   #include <unistd.h>

   #include <stdlib.h>

   #include <fcntl.h>
2. or declare the functions yourself

   #include <stdio.h>

   #include <unistd.h>

   #include <stdlib.h>

   #include <fcntl.h>

   char *ptsname(int fd);

   int posix_openpt(int flags);

   int grantpt(int fd);

   int unlockpt(int fd);

Hope this will fix the problem